# nn.LSTM not working together with functional_call for calculating the gradient

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, autograd

I have the following code:

```
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.stateless import functional_call
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn as nn

# This is the model
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, action_dim, z_dim, skill_length):
        super().__init__()
        print(action_dim)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(action_dim, action_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=action_dim, hidden_size=z_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(z_dim, z_dim)

    def forward(self, skill):
        a, b, c = skill.shape
        skill = skill.reshape(-1, skill.shape[-1])
        embed = self.lin1(skill)
        embed = embed.reshape(a, b, c)
        mean, _ = self.lstm(embed)
        mean = mean[:, -1, :]
        mean = self.lin2(mean)

        return mean

# This is the initialization function
def pars(model):
    params = {}
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if len(param.shape) == 1:
            init = torch.nn.init.constant_(param, 0)
        else:
            init = torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param)
        params[name] = nn.Parameter(init)
    return params

# Initializating the model
model = Encoder(4, 2, 5)
x = torch.rand(3, 5, 4)
params = pars(model)


# Running the model with functional_call and calculating gradient.
samp = functional_call(model, params, x)
grad_f = autograd.grad(torch.mean(samp), params.values(),
                       retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)
print(grad_f)
# grad_f has gradient for the linear layer, but None for the LSTM layer.

# Running the model without functional_call and calculating gradient.
samp = model(x)
grad = autograd.grad(torch.mean(samp), model.parameters(), retain_graph=True)
print(grad)
# grad has gradient for all layers, e.g., linears and lstm.
```

I know the problem is with the LSTM layer because when I use a linear layer with `nn.Linear`, then the gradient depends on std as well as the linear layer. Unfortunately, I do not know to resolve this problem. I'd appreciate any help.

*Edit: I heavily edited the code provided just to further simplify the example. This code can be copied and run.

**Update Dec 11, 2022**

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, action_dim, z_dim, skill_length):
        super().__init__()
        print(action_dim)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(action_dim, action_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=action_dim, hidden_size=z_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(z_dim, z_dim)

    def forward(self, skill):
        a, b, c = skill.shape
        skill = skill.reshape(-1, skill.shape[-1])
        embed = self.lin1(skill)
        embed = embed.reshape(a, b, c)
        mean, _ = self.lstm(embed)
        pdb.set_trace()
        grad1 = autograd.grad(mean.mean(), params.values(),
                              retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)
        # This gives gradient for the self.lin1 layer, and None for the LSTM
        grad2 = autograd.grad(mean.mean(), self.parameters(),
                              retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)
        # This gives gradient the LSTM, but None for the self.lin1 layer
        mean = mean[:, -1, :]
        mean = self.lin2(mean)

        return mean
```

When I run it the regular without `functional_call` and calling directly the model, then `autograd.grad(mean.mean(), self.parameters(), allow_unused=True, retain_graph=True)` has gradient for the self.lin1 and LSTM layer.

I don't know if this information is useful, but putting out there just in case.

Comment: Is `functional_call` a function you defined yourself? If so, can you please post the code as well?

Comment: No, `functional_call` comes directly from pytorch https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.stateless.functional_call.html

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you replace `nn.LSTM` with `nn.RNN` or `nn.GRU`?

Comment: In the documentation of `functional_call`, they mention the following: "If you want to apply the parametrization function to the value passed please set the key as `{submodule_name}.parametrizations.{parameter_name}.original`". Did you use this naming convention for your parameters?

Comment: @kmkurn Yes, it also happens with those options.

Comment: @rvinas I believe that's something added recently. I had read the documentation and that note wasn't there before. I am currently getting an error, but I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @rvinas To be clear, the error I get is: `AttributeError: 'LSTM' object has no attribute 'parametrizations'`. However, after reading the parametrizations tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/parametrizations.html I am not sure this is applicable to my case as I am not trying to have a specific initialization or parametrization of the parameters.

Comment: I tried running your example code but it fails when initialising the LSTM bias parameters with the orthogonal initialisation. Can you please post a working example code?

Comment: @kmkurn I have corrected it. Sorry about that.